# Can someone not feel i.e. neglect pain sensation?

Tags: emotion, pain

Ronda Rousey (UFC Women's Bantamweight Champion) once said on a talk show (Conan) that she can take a punch and not feel pain, she added that she knows what pain is and she can just simply neglect them without feeling it

Can anyone without Analgesia, Hypoalgesia or any other syndrome can neglect the feeling of pain with any training?

Comment: Subjective pain perception can be changed. There are studies on it, but I'm too lazy right now to dig them up, so a simple experiment for you: when it is winter and really, really cold outside, go to a place where it is a bit above freezing. Explose your arm, acclimatize, that is, let your skin get cold, and then pinch yourself. Now go outside, stand there for five minutes, and then pinch yourself. Now go back in your flat, wait, pinch. Then take a hot bath and pinch yourself. You will notice, that the intensity of pain will change, simply because of the temperature. Other factors work also.

Answer (score 1):

Totally neglect pain? Probably not, but mediate pain sensation? Definetly!

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304395989902303

> Results revealed that, in general, cognitive coping strategies are more effective in alleviating pain as compared to either no-treatment or expectancy controls. Each individual class of strategies significantly attenuates pain although the imagery methods are the most effective whereas pain acknowledging is the least effective.

Further reading:

- http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1364661308001575
- http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304395903002975